# Pandas map between two dataframes into column

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-manipulation

Let's say that I have a df1 like (there are more columns but only this one is relatable):

```
A
a1
a2
a3
```

and a df2 like:

```
A
a1
a3
a4
a7
```

The case is that df2 contains in column A (column names are the same both in df1 and df2) some of the values in df1, but not all of them. Now, I'd like to add a column "Found in df2?" to a df1, representing if the value was found or not. Example:

```
df1
A  Found in df2?
a1       Y
a2       N
a3       Y
```

I've tried np.where and some merging magic but couldn't wrap my head around this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `isin`:

```
df['found in df2'] = df['A'].isin(df2['A'].values)

print(df)

    A   found in df2
0   a1  True
1   a2  False
2   a3  True
```

---

Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a1','a2','a3']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a1','a3','a4','a7']})
```

Answer (score 1):

If using pandas cannot solve your problem, I suggest you to turn them into list/arrays such that it is easier to work with.

Here is one way to work around:

```py
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1,2,3]
})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1,3,4,7]
})

df1['Found in df2?'] = ['Y' if x in df2['A'].values else 'N' for x in df1['A'].values]
display(df1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas merge has an indicator feature that tells you in which sides of the merge a value is found.

Like this:

```
dfm = pd.merge(df1, df2[['A']], how="left", indicator=True)

dfm['Found in df2'] = dfm["_merge"] == "both"
```

You get a column `_merge` that tells you "left_only" or "both" depending on where the A values are found.  Use `how="outer"` if you want to know which values are only in `df2` too.

Now, merge may reorder rows in df1 based on the order of A. See other questions on SO how to counteract that, if needed.